# TextBox loses text when InvokeRequired == false

Tags: c#, winforms

This is modified code I found on this site.

When appending text to a TextBox and InvoveRequired is false the text will display in the box but the next time the function is called and InvokeRequired is true the text string placed by the first call is lost (""). Multiple calls when InvokeRequired is true work as expected.

comBox is a type TextBox with multline = true.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public void LogComText(string comText, bool newline)
    {
        if (comBox.InvokeRequired)
        {

            comBox.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
            {
                LogComText(comText, newline);
            }));
            return;
        }
        comBox.AppendText(comText);
        if (newline) comBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);


    }
```

Comment: That's suprising... could you create a short but *complete* program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I would definitely say that somewhere else in your program you do a `combBox.Text = ""` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it should work, maybe it has some thing to do with concurrency.
Try using `comBox.Invoke(...)` instead of `comBox.BeginInvoke(...)`
**Update:** <strike>The thing is when you use `BeginInvoke` the method calls may be invoked out of order.</strike>
That was wrong, calls to `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` are executed in order.

**Edit:**
It that doesn´t work make sure you don´t have any other place where you change the text in `comBox`.

If it still doesn´t work you might have to create a lock to make sure you don´t have two thread simultaneously writing to the textbox.

Something like this:

```
private static readonly object _comBoxSyncObj = new object();
public void LogComText(string comText, bool newline)
{
    if (comBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        comBox.Invoke(new Action(delegate
        {
            LogComText(comText, newline);
        }));
        return;
    }
    lock (_comBoxSyncObj)
    {
        comBox.AppendText(comText);
        if(newline) comBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

**Edit2:**
If the problem persists, you can add an event handler for the `TextChanged` event and put a breakpoint in it to se when the textbox get cleared.

Add this method and an eventhandler for `TextChanged` on comBox:

```
private void comBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comBox.TextLength == 0)
    {
        // Set a breakpoint here.
        Trace.WriteLine("TextBox empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: Both Invoke and beginInvoke have the same result.  I'll try the lock and post back.

Comment: Control.BeginInvoke, "Executes a delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's underlying handle was created on."

BeginInvoke just adds a message to the queue for the UI thread. Those messages will be processed in the order they were created.

Comment: @hemp, you´r right. I thought about the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.